# Custom MKPinAnnotationView Colours

Tags: iphone, mkpinannotationview

Is it possible to define custom colours for the MKPinAnnotationView colour rather than the default red, green or purple? Docs say no...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use annotation with color different from standard ones you should create your own image. 
    If Apple's docs say no, you should trust them - even if there's undocumented (using private api) way to do something it will likely cause your app to be rejected from app store.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. It is possible and doesn't involve any undocumented APIs:

[MKPinAnnotationView: Are there more than three colors available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185611/mkpinannotationview-are-there-more-than-three-colors-available)