# MKAnnotation change text colour?

Tags: mapkit, ios7.1

How do you change the text colour and background of a MapKit Annotation?

I am using MKAnnotation there doesn't seem to be a property I can use to change the text color or background color?

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: i guess it's the same question asked before. See this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847123/custom-mkpinannotationview-colours

Comment: Its not really the pin I want to change the color of its the actual text in the description since ios 7 its defaulted to white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I understand you basically want to override Mapkit annotation text color or something. I hope it helps your problem  https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/multirowcalloutannotationview

note : this framework may inspire you what should you customize annotation.

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for I will have a look in to this and let you know thanks.