# Custon MKPinAnnotationColor

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I have searched a bit on google, but didn't really found an answer to my question.
I want to create a pin with a different color, e.g. yellow or orange.

How should I do this? It seems that it's not possible to create one sending a UIColor to it. Should I design them myself and somehow change the pin to an own image?

Best regards,
Paul Peelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to do it yourself with your custom `MKAnnotationView`, I posted some customs colors I did on my own there :

[MKPinAnnotationView: Are there more than three colors available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185611/mkpinannotationview-are-there-more-than-three-colors-available/2066487#2066487)

Answer (score 0):

The 3 pin "colors" are actually series of different images (look in your `iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework`), so you can't create one by sending a UIColor.

You need to make a custom MKAnnotationView...