# iPhone: Create MKAnnotation

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

Can I create an `MKAnnotation`, or is it read only?  I have coordinates, but I am not finding it easy to manually create an `MKAnnotation` with using `setCoordinate`.

Ideas?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

*[MKAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)* is a protocol.  So you need to write your own annotation object that implements this protocol.  So your MyAnnotation header looks like:

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

// add an init method so you can set the coordinate property on startup
- (id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord;
```

and your implementation looks like (MyAnnotation.m):

```
- (id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord
{
    coordinate = coord;
    return self;
}
```

So to add your annotation to the map:

```
MyAnnotation * annotation = [[[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate] autorelease];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

If you wan't a title and subtitle on the annotation callout, you need to add the title and subtitle properties.

Comment: This is just what I needed.  Where would I put the - (id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord; method?  In my .h file or .m?

Comment: No problem.  I have updated the answer with some more detail :)

Comment: For some reason, I get no '-initWithCoord:' method found when I try to build and run.

Comment: Sorry.  My sample code was initWithCoord, it should be initWithCoordinate.

Comment: How to add image for annotation?

Comment: @NileshTupe Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185611/mkpinannotationview-are-there-more-than-three-colors-available/1963460#1963460

Comment: The whole point of protocols (and interfaces in Java) is to let you treat things as other things. So making a class called MyAnnotation, even in an example, is really not good. Whatever you are putting on the map should be a domain object, for instance, a Restaurant. Then you have that domain class implement this protocol, then you are mapping this positionable behavior onto it.

Answer (score 33):

In iPhone OS 4 there is a new class MKPointAnnotation which is a concrete implementation of the MKAnnotation protocol.

Comment: This is super handy if you only need basic annotations. Thanks!

Comment: MKPointAnnotation* pointAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    pointAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate;
    [mkMapView addAnnotation:pointAnnotation];

Answer (score 9):

Check apple MapCallouts project. Everything you need is in that file:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Ta ever so much, just what I was looking for.