# Database use in xcode for multiple locations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, annotations, mapkit

I am trying to make annotations on a map in Xcode for every gas station and major grocery store. Does anybody have a clue about how to go about this except for entering them in all by hand? Maybe a database of some sort?

And if you do have an idea, please explain so that I can follow along. Sorry, I am very new to this. :) Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to this data and just want to store it in the app, you should use [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

If you are looking for the data to begin with, see if [Factual](http://www.factual.com/data-apis/places) will work for you.

Comment: Cool! Just how do you use this though to plot annotations? Could you give me an example? Sorry, I' sure this is a silly question, but I am still trying to learn the ropes. :)

Comment: This question should be all you need to place an annotation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491791/how-to-add-a-map-annotation-on-mkmapview

Comment: Which link do I use? the link of the table or the individual data?

Comment: Is there any way to place a mass of annotations?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. How can I plot the data from the table on Factual as annotations without having to place them one by one?