# How to load JSON data on a apple map to put a marker IOS

Tags: ios, json, mkmapview, mapkit, apple-maps

Hi I have a file on a server json format with several map points:

```
["VALUE","proyect",[{"id":"1","name":"Frankie Johnnie & Luigo Too","address":"939 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA","lat":"37.386337","lng":"-122.085823"},morepoints..]]
```

I want to put these points as markers on my map in my ios app.
I've looked at several pages and here but I have not found anything and what I have tried does not work.

Any help,please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you first parse your JSON:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
NSAssert(array, @"%s: JSONObjectWithData error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
```

Second, you can then grab the array of locations out of that top-level array, create annotations for each location dictionary in that array, and add it to your map:

```
// the array of locations is the third object in the top-level array

NSArray *locations = array[2];

// now iterate through this array of locations

for (NSDictionary *location in locations)
{
    // grab the latitude and longitude strings

    NSString *latitudeString = location[@"lat"];
    NSAssert(latitudeString, @"No latitude");
    NSString *longitudeString = location[@"lng"];
    NSAssert(longitudeString, @"No longitude");

    // create the annotation and add it to the map

    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([latitudeString doubleValue], [longitudeString doubleValue]);
    annotation.title = location[@"name"];
    annotation.subtitle = location[@"address"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

---

Having said that, I must say that I don't care for the JSON format:

```
["VALUE","proyect",[{"id":"1","name":"Frankie Johnnie & Luigo Too","address":"939 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA","lat":"37.386337","lng":"-122.085823"},morepoints..]]
```

It's a questionable design for us to have to divine what the first, second, and third objects in this array are. We shouldn't have to cryptically grab `array[2]` to get the array of locations.

Arrays should be used for lists of equivalent items (e.g. the array of locations makes perfect sense). But this top level array is a little more dubious, with three very semantically different types of values, with nothing in the JSON to indicate what these three items are.

If you're stuck with this JSON format, then, fine, the above code should do the job. But hopefully you can change the top level structure here to be a dictionary, rather than an array, where you can use key names to identify the various items in this top-level dictionary, e.g.:

```
{"id" : "VALUE", "project" : "proyect", "locations" : [{"id":"1","name":"Frankie Johnnie & Luigo Too","address":"939 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA","lat":"37.386337","lng":"-122.085823"},morepoints..]}
```

I didn't know what those first two values were supposed to be, so I just called them `id` and `project`, but you should obviously use names that truly reflect what those first two values are. But the key concept is to use a dictionary, where you can refer to the array of locations by name. For example, if the JSON was changed like I've suggested here, the code to parse it would become:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
NSAssert(dictionary, @"%s: JSONObjectWithData error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);

NSArray *locations = dictionary[@"locations"];
```

Also, as a stylistic observation, many people would generally represent the latitude and longitude values as numbers (without the quotation marks), and the `NSJSONSerialization` would parse them as `NSNumber` objects rather than `NSString` objects. But that's up to you.

Comment: Rob, Im trying to put a better marker in my map with your solution but I cant it. How Can I put MapAnotations?THANKS :)!

Comment: @natijauskas I'm not sure what you mean by "better marker", but I'd suggest you (a) check out the [Annotating Maps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW1) section of the _Location and Maps Programming Guide_; (b) search on S.O. (or google) for articles on custom annotations as this has been covered exhaustively elsewhere; and (c) if you still are unclear, post a new question and I'm sure someone can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to parse the JSON to retrieve the data for each point and then create an MKMapViewAnnotation instance of your own for each and add them to the map.

More info here: http://maybelost.com/2011/01/a-basic-mapview-and-annotation-tutorial/

and here: [How to add a Map annotation on MKMapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491791/how-to-add-a-map-annotation-on-mkmapview)

Info about parsing JSON here: http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/