# How to set marker in ios MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

How to set marker in `MKMapView` 
Here is my code to set a latitude and longitude but i dont know how to set marker 
please give me solution.

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = latitude;
    center.longitude = longitude;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    location.latitude  = center.latitude;  //37.250556;
    location.longitude = center.longitude; //-96.358333;

    span.latitudeDelta = 0.05;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.05;

    region.span = span;
    region.center = location;

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];
```

Comment: marker means pin annotation ?

Comment: This question is a duplicate and shows no research effort. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878758/iphone-create-mkannotation?lq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491791/how-to-add-a-map-annotation-on-mkmapview

Comment: not required duplicat pin Need only one pin in mapview

Comment: The dude means the question is a duplicate. It has been asked here before and you should have searched for the answer before posting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useful tutorial: [maybelost.com/2011/01/a-basic-mapview-and-annotation-tutorial](http://maybelost.com/2011/01/a-basic-mapview-and-annotation-tutorial)

```
// Add the annotation to our map view 
MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Buckingham Palace" andCoordinate:location];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
[newAnnotation release];
```