# CLLocationManager - loading MKAnnotation after Location Services Prompt

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have an application that needs to detect the users location an drop some `MKAnnotations` around it on the `MKMapView`. How can I get notified about wether the user has selected YES on the Location Services prompt in order to then call my method to get the users location and add the annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen in the location manager delegate didUpdateToLocation;

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    MyAnnotation * annotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

You will need to create a MyAnnotation class.  Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2878806/1535038

Comment: I've implemented that method but its not being called. What could it be?

Comment: Did you set the delegate of the CLLocationManager to your class (most likely self)?

Comment: Just want to add onto Jame's comment, don't forget to conform to the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol in your header file too!