# Saving UIView contents in iOS 4 with real size of the images inside (i.e. scale contentes up for save)

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios4, calayer, retina-display

I have an UIView with many UIImageViews as subviews. The app runs on iOS4 and I use images with retina display resolution (i.e. the images load with scale = 2)

I want to save the contents of the UIView ... BUT ... have the real size of the images inside. I.e. the view has size 200x200 and images with scale=2 inside, I'd like to save a resulting image of 400x400 and all the images with their real size.

Now what comes first to mind is to create a new image context and load again all images inside with scale=1 and that should do, but I was wondering if there is any more elegant way to do that? Seems like a waist of memory and processor time to reload everything again since it's already done ...

p.s. if anyone has an answer - including code would be nice

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Implementation for rendering **any UIView** to image (working also for retina display).

helper.h file:

```
@interface UIView (Ext) 
- (UIImage*) renderToImage;
@end
```

and belonging implementation in helper.m file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UIView (Ext)
- (UIImage*) renderToImage
{
  // IMPORTANT: using weak link on UIKit
  if(UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
  {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
  } else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
  }

  [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  
  return image;
}
```

0.0 is the scale factor. The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.

**QuartzCore.framework** also should be put into the project because we are calling function on the layer object.

To enable weak link on UIKit framework, click on the project item in left navigator, click the project target -> build phases -> link binary and choose "optional" (weak) type on UIKit framework.

Here is [library](https://github.com/prcela/ns-extensions) with similar extensions for UIColor, UIImage, NSArray, NSDictionary, ...

Comment: What's the point of checking to see if you can use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`? Is it for backward-compatibility?

Comment: This solution also requires the QuartzCore framework, for the renderInContext method.

Comment: @pixelfreak this is because UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is only available on iOS 4 +.

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
 Is it works ? i think 0.0 replace with 1.0..

Comment: Anyone know where the "general tab" is? I don't see it. UIKit only has   option for "required" or "optional". Also, i had to turn ARC off for helper.m but still get an error with "renderInContext" not found. Also, no implementation/usage so this answer could really use some editing. I'd love to see how it works, if it does!

Comment: I have updated the answer. The QuartzCore framework should be included into project. Also I updated the info for the new XCode.

Answer (score 4):

I've performed such thing to save the pins from the MKMapView as a PNG file (in retina display): [MKPinAnnotationView: Are there more than three colors available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185611/mkpinannotationview-are-there-more-than-three-colors-available/2066487#2066487)

Here's an extract of the crucial part that performs the saving of a `UIView` (`theView`) using its retina definition:

```
-(void) saveMyView:(UIView*)theView {
    //The image where the view content is going to be saved.
    UIImage* image = nil;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(theView.frame.size, NO, 2.0);
    [theView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData* imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSString* targetPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [self writablePath], @"thisismyview.png" ];
    [imgData writeToFile:targetPath atomically:YES]; 
}
```

-(NSString*) writablePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return documentsDirectory;
}

Comment: Hey +1 for mentioning UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions ... gosh there's a ton of new random functions like that coming out with every minor iOS update ... I'm getting tired :)

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is a new one to me too.  Should look over the updates more carefully...

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Works great! Needed to include #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
And add framework to project.

Answer (score 2):

The key is that the third parameter to UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is the *scale*, which determines how the image will ultimately be written out.

If you always want the real pixel dimensions, use [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] to get the current scale of the screen:

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewSizeInPoints, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);`

If you use scale=1.0 on iPhone4, you will get an image with its dimension in *points* and the result is scaled down from the true pixel count. If you manually write the image out to a 640x960 dimension (eg: passing pixels as the first parameter), it will actually be the scaled-down image that is scaled back up which looks about as terrible as you imagine it would look.

Comment: According to the docs, setting the scale argument to 0.0 is the same as setting it to [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale].

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just create a new graphics context at the desired size, use a CGAffineTransform to scale it down, render the root UIView's root layer, restore the context to the original size and render the image?  Haven't tried this for retina content, but this seems to work well for large images that have been scaled down in UIImageViews...

something like:

```
CGSize originalSize = myOriginalImage.size; //or whatever

//create context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(originalSize);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context); //1 original context

// translate/flip the graphics context (for transforming from CG* coords to UI* coords
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, originalSize.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

//original image
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0,0,originalSize.width,originalSize.height), myOriginalImage.CGImage);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);//1 restore to original for UIView render;

//scaling
CGFloat wratio = originalSize.width/self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat hratio = originalSize.height/self.view.frame.size.height;

//scale context to match view size
CGContextSaveGState(context); //1 pre-scaled size
CGContextScaleCTM(context, wratio, hratio);

//render 
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];

CGContextRestoreGState(context);//1  restore to pre-scaled size;

UIImage *exportImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Hi Steven, correct me if I'm wrong but isn't that actually having a scaled down render (ie using 1/4 of the pixel image data) which is than scaled up or the core graphics works in a different way?

Comment: I could be wrong here because I'm a bit fuzzy on the specifics of this part of Quartz, but with testing with above has shown that it is not a scaled down render.  At first, I specifically created a scaled down bitmap context, rescaled, and rendered using the bitmap context but the result was crap (as you would expect). The above method however, provides a crisp image as long as the original sources are of reasonable size/quality.

Comment: As an afterword, this above code assumes that myOriginalImage is larger than the UIView point size (retina or otherwise)

Comment: I'm not the CG king myself too ... I'll give your solution a try though, really interesting if it's really not scaled down

Answer (score 0):

Import QuartzCore (Click main project, Build Phases, import) and where you need it add:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

My imageViews are properties, if your are not, ignore the `.self` and pass the imageViews into the function as parameters, then call `renderInContext` on the two images in a new `UIGraphicsCurrentContext`

```
- (UIImage *)saveImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.mainImage.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);

    [self.backgroundImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    [self.mainImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *savedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return savedImage;
}
```