# Combining two UIImageView to an UIImage with respect to their current size, rotation and positions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In one of my apps I am trying to combine two UIImageViews into a single UIImage. Bottom one is from the camera and the top one is something like a badge. The user can drag, rotate and scale the one at the top.

My question is, how can i save these two UIImageViews into a single UIImage at the end of all drag, rotate and scale operations?

Edit: I want to keep the original size of the bottom image.

Answer (score 1):

This post : [Saving UIView contents in iOS 4 with real size of the images inside (i.e. scale contentes up for save)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213529/saving-uiview-contents-in-ios-4-with-real-size-of-the-images-inside-i-e-scale) shows how you can get a UIImage from any UIView.

Basically, you can adapt its solution, using a UIView container for your 2 UIImageViews.

Comment: What if I want to keep the original size of the bottom image?

Comment: if your 'top/badge' imageView fits into the other, you can add it as a subview (an UIImageView in another UIImageView), and use this method on the biggest/container UIImageView. 

And, when you're lost, don't forget to cut your 'big' problems in smaller ones : 
1/ get a UIImage from a UIView
2/ resize that UIImage to the size of your camera's image
(here's a useful link addressing both problems : http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/10/01/scaling-images-and-creating-thumbnails-from-uiviews/)