# How to grab badge icon image out of iphone simulator?

Tags: iphone, image, sdk, badge

I found the response to a post about MKPinAnnotationView icons very helpful.  See: [MKPinAnnotationView: Are there more than three colors available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185611/mkpinannotationview-are-there-more-than-three-colors-available/2066487#2066487).

I want to do the same thing getting the icon badge out of the simulator so that I can use it elsewhere as a static image.  I'm guessing I would get the UITabBarItem view and drill down the subviews until I find it, and then do the same thing as in the post above to get the icon out.  Is that correct?

I'm hoping to get direct input from "yonel" as well to say THANK YOU (can't post a comment on that thread) for the images from the map.  I'd been looking for those for many days.

Any input here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @yonel, can you tell me if I'm on the right track?  And THANKS for the map pins in the referenced post above. Very helpful. And clever getting them out of the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably easily find it by installing and running [UIKit Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor)

Comment: Very nice--got exactly what I needed!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [this excellent PSD](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2010/08/12/iphone-4-gui-psd-retina-display/) and get anything you need.

Comment: This is really sweet, but I can't use it in production, according to their website.  Nice for mock-ups, tho.