# How to get click event from a button added over MKAnnotationView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton, mkmapview

Anyone know if there's a way to get click event from a `button` that is added to `MKAnnotationView`, this `button` is used as label just to display the name of each pin on the `map` , now I successd to show a custom `view` (which contains image, text ....) when the `pin` is clicked so i need to do the same thing when the button (label) is clicked.

Thanks for any advice you can provide.

code for `button` in `MKAnnotationView`:

```
UIButton * pinButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 28)];
[pinButton.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1]]; 
[pinButton setCenter:CGPointMake(pinAnnotationView.center.x + 70, pinAnnotationView.center.y + 10)]; 
[pinButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pinLabelClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[pinAnnotationView addSubView:pinButton]; 
[pinButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: How are you creating the button?

Comment: There is no button in `MKAnnotationView`, basically your touching the `MKAnnotationView`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The standard UI approach is to use the callout view and add an accessory button as progrmr shows.

However, if you must add a button directly to the `MKAnnotationView`, the problems with your approach are that the `MKPinAnnotationView`'s default frame (which can't easily be changed) is smaller than the button you're adding so most of the button will not respond to touches and even if you switch to using an `MKAnnotationView` and increase the frame size, the `MKMapView` will prevent the button from getting any touches.

What you'll need to do is add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the button (use the gesture handler's action method instead of an addTarget on the button) and add the button to a plain `MKAnnotationView` with an appropriate frame size instead of an `MKPinAnnotationView`.

Example:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
        viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *annView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView 
            dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"pin"];
    if (annView == nil)
    {
        annView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                      reuseIdentifier:@"pin"] autorelease];

        annView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50);

        UIButton *pinButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        pinButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 28);
        pinButton.tag = 10;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
            initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinButtonTap:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [pinButton addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [tap release];

        [annView addSubview:pinButton]; 
    }

    annView.annotation = annotation;

    UIButton *pb = (UIButton *)[annView viewWithTag:10];
    [pb setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return annView;
}

- (void) handlePinButtonTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) gestureRecognizer.view;
    MKAnnotationView *av = (MKAnnotationView *)[btn superview];
    id<MKAnnotation> ann = av.annotation;
    NSLog(@"handlePinButtonTap: ann.title=%@", ann.title);
}
```

Note that this will prevent the map view's `didSelectAnnotationView` delegate method from firing.  If you need that method to fire (in *addition* to the button's gesture handler method), then add the following:

```
//in the view controller's interface:
@interface YourVC : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

//where the UITapGestureRecognizer is created:
tap.delegate = self;

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
        shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer
            :(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply it's very useful, however i want just know how to add pins in this case ??

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The annotations can be added as usual by calling addAnnotation.  Do you mean how to get the default "pin" image?

Comment: i'm talking about pins (icon) which must be connected to each button (label).

Comment: In viewForAnnotation, you'll have to do `annView.image = your-UIImage;` (or you could create a UIImageView and addSubview to the annView) using your own images.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185611/mkpinannotationview-are-there-more-than-three-colors-available/2066487#2066487) has some default pin images you can use.

Comment: Ok thanks very much now i understand what you mean, it's not worth   using MKPinAnnotationView.

Comment: sorry but when i used annView.image = myImage the button losed event click again

Comment: it's work fine when i created a UIImageView and addSubview to the annView as you suggested. thank's again

Comment: Now i have another problem related to this solution, the pins are misplaced on the map (shifted) and when i zoomIn/zoomOut they change places, plz any idea about this problem ? thanks again

Comment: Don't do this. I added a tap gesture recognizer to the custom annotation view class, and pretty soon MKMapView stopped calling my delegate methods like regionDidChangeAnimated: and viewForAnnotation: randomly.

Comment: @Anurag, thanks, were you able to find a solution or workaround?

Comment: @AnnaKarenina - I tried this approach from the Asynchrony Blog last year which worked for me - http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/. Their solution is quite complicated as it tries to work within the limitations of the map's internal workings.

Answer (score 3):

I added a button to the callout view (in my app) using this code (reduced for clarity):

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map 
        viewForAnnotation:(StationItem*)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"stationViewId";

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;  // use default user location view
    }

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = 
        (MKPinAnnotationView*) [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil) {
        // if an existing pin view was not available, create one
        annotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];

        // add rightAccessoryView
        UIButton* aButton = [UIButton buttonWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 30)];
        [aButton setTitle:@"Directions" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = aButton;
    }

    annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.animatesDrop   = NO;

    return annotationView;
}
```

After doing this you need to implement the MKMapViewDelegate to handle callback to the delegate when the button is tapped:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

Comment: thanks but i can't use rightCalloutAccessoryView because i disabled canShowCallout, to let the click on pin show just the custom view which i created.

Answer (score -1):

try passing the touches to the subview:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 [pinButton touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

I'm surprised you have a problem though if your buttonView is in front? try making sure it is:
[self bringSubviewToFront:pinButton];

Comment: the button apear near the pin but it's not clickable i've tried bringSubviewToFront but no result.