# Custom MKAnnotationView intermittently recognize touch

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have a custom `MKAnnotationView` that I am loading from an `XIB`. When I first load the mapview, I have several standard `MKAnnotationView`.

When a user selects one, the custom `MKAnnotationView` is presented.  I would like for the user to be able to tap anywhere inside the custom annotation view to present a new view controller.

What I've tried (all of these were suggestions I found here on StackOverflow):

- Overriding hit test is the custom MKAnnotationView class.  The issue here is that CGPoint would return as nil most of the time. ([How do I make a MKAnnotationView touch sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648263/how-do-i-make-a-mkannotationview-touch-sensitive))
- Adding a tap gesture to a UIButton and adding that button to the custom annotation view in the viewForAnnotation delegate method.  ([How to get click event from a button added over MKAnnotationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941199/how-to-get-click-event-from-a-button-added-over-mkannotationview)).  This never really worked and it didn't make much sense to me.  Adding a tap gesture to a button seems redundant.
- Adding KVO to the annotation view.  (http://www.jakeri.net/2009/12/custom-callout-bubble-in-mkmapview-final-solution/).  This caused an issue because the annotationView that was added to the map seemed to get deallocated before sending the notification.
- Adding a clear button in the XIB that is the size of the custom view and adding a target/selector to it.  I also make sure to bring it to the front of the parent view.

What is strange is that if I drag the map while the annotation is present, the button works fine. The issue only shows up when I first show the custom view.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please tell what exactly is not working when using first solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout out the MKMapKit Delegate documentation it has lots of good methods you can use to do exactly what you're trying to do. I would **absolutely** not try and add a UIButton to a annotation view.

Managing Annotation Views
– mapView:viewForAnnotation:
– mapView:didAddAnnotationViews:
– mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:
Dragging an Annotation View
– mapView:annotationView:didChangeDragState:fromOldState:
Selecting Annotation Views
**– mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:**
– mapView:didDeselectAnnotationView:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation  {
if([annotation isKindOfClass: [MKUserLocation class]])
{
    return nil;
}
else if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MYCLASS class]])
{
    static NSString *annotationViewReuseIdentifier = @"annotationViewReuseIdentifier";
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationViewReuseIdentifier];
    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationViewReuseIdentifier];
    }

    //Add an Image!
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trashMarker.png"];

    //Move the Frame Around!
    [annotationView setFrame:CGRectMake(annotationView.frame.origin.x, annotationView.frame.origin.y - annotationView.frame.size.height, annotationView.frame.size.height, annotationView.frame.size.width)];

    //Finally Set it as the annotation!
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    //Return the annotationView so the MKMapKit can display it!
    return annotationView;
}}
```

Your subclass of the MKAnnotation (IE conforms to  protocol) should contain a tag by default (I think) but if it doesn't just add one yourself with a property so you can distinguish between the different markers on the map. Your method should look something like this,

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view  {
MYCLASS *selectedMapPin = view.annotation;
if(selectedMapPin.tag == MY_PIN_TAG)
{
    //SHOW VIEW CONTROLLER
}}
```

For more examples you can refer to our open source project for Green Up Vermont

[Green Up Vermont iOS App](https://github.com/EJEHardenberg/green-apps.git)