# Multiple Arrays of Annotations, Different Pin Color for Each Array?

Tags: iphone, ios, annotations, mkmapview

I have three arrays of annotations in my app, foodannotations, gasannotations, and shoppingannotations.  I want each array of annotations to show a different colored pin.  I am currently using

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)sheratonmap viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    NSLog(@"Welcome to the Map View Annotation");

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"Annotation Identifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinview = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                     initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];

    pinview.animatesDrop=YES;
    pinview.canShowCallout=YES;
    pinview.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

    UIButton* rightbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightbutton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinview.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightbutton;

    return pinview;
}
```

How can I set this up to use the three different pin colors for each array of annotations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Have you defined a custom class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol in which you added some property that identifies what kind of annotation it is?  Or have you defined three separate classes (one for each type of annotation) that implement `MKAnnotation`?

Assuming you've defined one annotation class in which you have an `int` property called say `annotationType` in your annotation class, then you can do this in `viewForAnnotation`:

```
int annType = ((YourAnnotationClass *)annotation).annotationType;
switch (annType)
{
    case 0 :   //Food
        pinview.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    case 1 :   //Gas
        pinview.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    default :  //default or Shopping
        pinview.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
}
```

A couple of other things:

- You should use the [`dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW20) method
- Instead of using addTarget:action and a custom method to handle the callout button press, use the map view's delegate method [`calloutAccessoryControlTapped`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204-CH3-SW14).  In that delegate method, you can access the annotation using `view.annotation`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to create a custom `MKAnnotation` and have a custom property (most propbably a typedef enum) to distinguish between the different types of annotations.

```
typedef enum {
    Food,
    Gas,
    Shopping
} AnnotationType
```

After that you can set your colors conditionally `if (annotation.annotationType == Food) { set pinColor }`

Of course you can use a switch statement for the `AnnotationType` for having clearer code:

```
switch(annotation.annotationType) {
    case Food:
        do something;
        break;
    case Gas:
        do something;
        break;
    case Shopping:
        do something;
        break;
}
```

See following question for more info on adding more colors (if you want to extend your app later on) :

[MKPinAnnotationView: Are there more than three colors available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185611/mkpinannotationview-are-there-more-than-three-colors-available/2066487#2066487)

---

Here's a code snippet from a [tutorial](http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/) that show's heavy modifications:

```
calloutMapAnnotationView.contentHeight = 78.0f;
UIImage *asynchronyLogo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"asynchrony-logo-small.png"];
UIImageView *asynchronyLogoView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:asynchronyLogo] autorelease];
asynchronyLogoView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 2, asynchronyLogoView.frame.size.width, asynchronyLogoView.frame.size.height);
[calloutMapAnnotationView.contentView addSubview:asynchronyLogoView];
```

HTH

Comment: is there no way that I can do this using the built in mkpinannotationview and pinview.pincolor=____?

Comment: yes, you can also use the pinColor property of your `MKAnnotationView` to do that. Also i've updated my question with a more relevant link.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to get to work with that right now!